Issue trying to use NuGet package MailKit in Xamarin project
I'm trying to send emails directly through my Xamarin Android application using MailKit.
I've installed the latest versions of MailKit and MimeKit through NuGet package manager, but when I run the code:
var message = New MimeMessage();
I get an error message:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load the file 'I18N

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/1621

The solution posted there resolved my issue, thank you.
